# why the function returns value to the previous function when it is not returned in the code?

Tags: c, recursion, return

why the following code is returning the output even if I am not returning the output of variable a to the previous function.

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int a;
    if (n <= 1) 
        return 1;
    else
        a = n*fact(n-1);
}
int main()
{
    int c=fact(5);
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In short, if you declare a function to return a value, you *must* return a value, anything else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So, your program exhibits undefined behavior.